# Telerik RadGrid grouping disappears after auto-postback from another control

Tags: telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I have a page with a Telerik RadGrid and a Telerik drop-down list. The grid items are grouped using the `<GroupByExpressions>` element. When an item is selected in the drop-down, the page posts back to itself and **the grid is still in grouping mode, but everything is in one unlabeled group.**

**Is there away to prevent this** or is there way to restore the correct grouping behaviour by rebinding on the client side or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! It turned out, upon the drop-down selection, the grid was assigned a new data 
source that didn't have any items with a value for the grouped field.

The reason I asked the question here before checking is that I automatically assumed it had something to do with the control's perceived flakiness.

I'm just leaving this here in case anyone happened to be in the same situation.